# watir webdriver get into iframe and get src of elements and click on link

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

With Watir-Webdriver I want to go change the focus to the iframe and get the link that is inside it.

Here is the html code

```html
<iframe id="top_right" src="otherwebsite.com/need content src">
<a href="need this"> <img src="need this" /> </a>
```

So what I would like is to go into the `iframe`, get the src of it, capture the `href` and the `src` from the `img` element and in the end click on these elements retrieving the data.

This is my attempt using Ruby:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'somesite.com'
b.wait
f = b.frame(:id => 'top_right').link(:index => 1).click
```

I have got until here but unfortunately i still get the following response:

```ruby
in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:index=>1, :tag_name=>"a"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

so if anybody have some help it would be great tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to click the second link (`:index=>1`) in the frame. Looks like the frame does not have two links. Try clicking the first link (`:index=>0`):

```
b.frame(:id => 'top_right').link(:index => 0).click
```

Comment: tnx...legendo.. One more question how to get atributtes of some elements like href or from img src

Comment: Please create a new question.